# Bad information computing when building a Qt Slog

Tags: c++, qt

Hey guys I am trying to make the following slot: The user should input a sequence of numbers in a line edit with spaces between them (for example: 5 10 15 10 2) I want these numbers to be stored into a vector of integers. After they are all read, I want the values of the vector to be changed in the following way - starting from the second element up to the end, every element should be equal to the following: `vector[i] = vector[i] - vector[i-1]`. Again, this doesn't count for the first one. I will do some more computing, but It would appear that I can't get this done quite right yet.

The layout is the following: a button, a lineEdit and a Label.
This is the header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVector>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QVector<int> vec;
private slots:
    void compute();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And the implementation:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit
            , SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(compute()));
    connect(ui->pushButton
            , SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(compute()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow :: compute()
{
    // Read user input
    QString numbers = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString tmp; // create temp string which will be used to store the temp substrings of each int
   numbers+="   ";
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i].isDigit())
        {
            tmp +=numbers[i];
        }
        else
        {
            bool ok = true;
            int iTime = tmp.toInt(&ok, 10);
            vec.push_back((iTime));
            tmp="";
        }
    }
    //compute the real vector that we will search the max subarray from
    for(int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        vec[i] = vec[i] - vec[i-1];
    }


    int tt = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z != vec.size(); z++)
    {
        tt+= vec[z];

    }
    ui->label->setText( QString::number(tt));
}
```

I won't post the main function since it is the standard one when you create a Qt GUI aplication. So, the problem is, the following line:  `ui->label->setText( QString::number(tt));` always prints zero to the label. I made this program in code blocks, without the Qt GUI libraries and I got it working. I am intrigued where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int z = 0; z != vec.size(); z++)
```

Should be:

```
for(int z = 0; z < vec.size(); z++)
```

Comment: Doesn't really fix it, I was playing arround with random conditions which might be causing this. Your suggestion is an improvement to the code and removes a huge possible mistake, but my flaw still stands.

Comment: @Bloodcount If you print to `std::cout` what `vec[z]` is in the loop, does it just give you zeroes?